Log file not created and no error has been shown for logs. (AdonisJs 6)
I am trying to add info/error logs in log files. For that, i make changes in logger.ts file and controller file. Both file's code i mansion below. I also add "pino-pretty" package in my project. Please help me to add logs in some files to further checks. Please let me know if any other changes are needed. adonis.js version 6
logger.ts
import env from '#start/env'
import app from '@adonisjs/core/services/app'
import { defineConfig, targets } from '@adonisjs/core/logger'

const loggerConfig = defineConfig({ 
    default: 'app', 
    loggers: { 
                app: { 
                    enabled: true, 
                    name: env.get('APP_NAME'), 
                    level: env.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'info'),  
                    transport: {
                        targets: targets()
                          .push({
                            target: 'pino-roll',
                            level: 'info',
                            options: {
                              file: '/var/log/apps/adonisjs.log',
                              frequency: 'daily',
                              mkdir: true,
                            },
                          })
                          .toArray(),
                   },
                  redact: {
                    paths: ['password', '*.password'],
                  },
  
            },
        }, 
    })
export default loggerConfig

declare module '@adonisjs/core/types' { 
    export interface LoggersList extends InferLoggers<typeof loggerConfig> {} 
}

controller file
import logger from '@adonisjs/core/services/logger'
export default class LocationsController {   
async index({ request, response }: HttpContext) { 
    try { 
       logger.info('this is an info message') 
       logger.debug('request', request.all())
     } catch (e) {
     }
   }
 }


I only needed to remove the first forward slash (/) from the file path:
options: {
    file: 'var/log/apps/adonisjs.log',
    frequency: 'daily',
    mkdir: true,
},

